# Segmented addresses in real mode colliding into the same physical address

Tags: x86, x86-16, low-level, real-mode, memory-segmentation

I know that in real mode addressing if I want to calculate physical address when I am given the segment+offset I need to use the equation:
physical address=segment*16+offset

What I don't got is how there are no colliding in this form. I can simply take address 0x1000:0x0010 that will be translated into pyhsical address 0x10010 and also take pyhsical address 0x1001:0x0000 that will be translated into the same pyhsical address 010010.

Wouldn't it be more efficient to just save 4 bits for segment and 16 bits for offset and then the physical address will be segment<<16 + offset? (and then there is one to one mapping between segment+offset and physical address)

Comment: That's right, there are many seg:off pairs that are all the same linear address.  Apparently having a small "paragraph" size was useful to avoid wasting memory for things that needed to be segment-aligned.  Fortunately real-mode and segmentation are irrelevant most of the time, we can just use 32-bit mode with a flat memory model if we need more than a trivial amount of memory.

Comment: Exact cross-site duplicate on retrocomputing.SE: [Why was segment register value scaled by such a small factor of 16 on i8086?](//retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1016)  - yes, paragraph alignment would have wasted more memory if the shift had been larger (8 or 16).  The CPU normally works with 8 and 16-bit values, so at least 8-bit segment regs are natural.  And since other regs are 16-bit, it makes sense that "special" regs are also 16-bit, even if we didn't have the motivation of using a small shift count.